# How can I properly render multiple layers/components in game?

Tags: 2d, architecture, love2d

I'm making a Love2D board game video game, which has multiple different components which need to be run and displayed on the screen at the same time. For example, I need to display the board, the characters, and the UI. Ideally, I would like to store each component in a seperate file (similar to Unix philosphy) In what way should I go about this?

My first idea was to create a screen/gamestate for each of these componenets, and stack them on top of each other so each is running/displaying at the same time. This feels like it's not a very proper solution so I'm open to other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> My first idea was to create a screen/gamestate for each of these components, and stack them on top of each other so each is running/displaying at the same time. This feels like it's not a very proper solution so I'm open to other ideas.

Seems like a fine solution. Especially as a first implementation.

After that, you might see if some parts are static and can be rendered to a canvas instead.

I'd only steer away from the "draw them on top of each other" plan if some aren't visible at all. Then you might have a list of drawables for each gamestate.